# what is the benefit of recreate image through php

Tags: php, image

Im new to image processing in php and the only reason that i can think of re-creating image through php is the potential to detect malicious code in the image. what would be the others reasons to use php to process image?

Comment: sorry as English is not my first language, I tried to phrase my opinion as proper as possible...but I dont understand the down votes as I cant find some legit reasons...

Comment: Resizing, rotating, cropping, adjusting quality, adding content... so many more things

Comment: @rjdown but these can be done through css..

Comment: They can be done through CSS, but say you have a page full of thumbnails. Would your user want to wait while a hundred 5000x5000 images download? No, it will be a lot quicker if he only downloads a small version with a fraction of the file size. PHP can automatically create these, and that's just one example.

Comment: @rjdown sorry if I got it wrong on the php process, but wouldnt generating  an image would make the file size even bigger?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. What makes you think that?

Comment: @rjdown because php needs to re-create the image and then scale down..., but wouldn't it also be easier to simply ask user to upload a small image instead?

Comment: It would be inconvenient for the user, so you don't want that.

Comment: @Andrew The thumbnail image generated by PHP would be no larger in file size than the one created by the user - it has gone through exactly the same process. Many of the things we get computers to do can be done by hand, but that doesn't mean it's a waste of time programming computers to do them for us.

Comment: @IMSoP okay, point taken. thanks for your explanation! Beside from code injection and decrease loading time, all the effect can still possible to be done through css.. I just dont want to reinvent the wheel as css primarily is to add effect on display, not php...

Comment: @Andrew Er, yes, there's often more than one way to do things, with pros and cons on each side. "All right... all right... but apart from better sanitation and medicine and education and irrigation and public health and roads and a freshwater system and baths and public order... what have the Romans done for us?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can easily resize user-uploaded images into multiple sizes to optimize page loads, you can cut parts of them, crop them to an exact size, or just convert them to the very same format.
Also you can easily add a watermark image onto them.

You can look around for a library you need here:
http://php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php

Comment: maybe the watermark part is harder to implement through css, but the others parts can be done through css. Doesnt resizing image through php will generate a larger image file size which slower page loads? Sorry if I offended, I am just curious and wanted to know the reasons behind it badly...

Comment: No they won't necessarily be larger. I mean, if you are creating 200x200 pixel thumbnail images from the uploaded 1080p images, they will definitely speed up load times. And you are storing the final images in a format you like. For example you can convert all image to PNG format, and you can apply pngcrush on all of them to further shrink the size.

Answer (score 0):

The main benefit would be, that you can react to user demands - for example fetching some information from a database (like the username) and printing this into the image. Or just add the time. And the difference to adding a watermark just using css or js: The user got the branded version only! If the watermark is added with css or js it can be easily removed...

One other thing might be, that you can deliver images which aren't stored in an public accessible path (therefore nobody can acces the image directly).